# Laravel5 でviewにデータを受け渡す時にエラーが出る

Tags: laravel

ブラウザで表示させようとすると`Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.`と表示されます。

view

```
@section('content')

@foreach($data as $row)
 <tr>
  <td>{{ $row->id }}</td>
  <td>{{ $row->title }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach


@endsection
```

controller

```
    public function index()
    {

    $data['posts']=DB::table('posts')->get();
    var_dump($data);
    return View('post/index',['data' => $data]);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$data['posts']にテーブルの抽出結果を入れているので、
foreachでループしながら参照するのではなく$dataでなく$data['posts']です。
そのため、$row（=$data['posts']）は配列（正確にはCollectionクラス)なのでidという属性はもっていないと言われています。

修正箇所としてはコントローラー出直す場合、

```
$data=DB::table('posts')->get();
```

ビューで直す場合、

```
@foreach($data['posts'] as $row)
```